# Fill empty Pandas column based on condition on substring

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have this dataset with the following data. I have a Job_Title column and I added a Categories column that I want to use to categorize my job titles. For example, all the job titles that contains the word 'Analytics' will be categorize as Data. This label Data will appear on the Categories table.

[image: Dataset 1]

I have created a dictionary with the words I want to identify on the Job_Title column as key and the values I want to add on the Categories column as values.

```
#Creating a new dictionary with the new categories
cat_type_dic = {}
cat_type_file = open("categories.txt")
for line in cat_type_file:
   key, value = line.split(";")
   cat_type_dic[key] = value

print(cat_type_dic)
```

Then, I tried to create a loop based on a condition. Basically, if the key on the dictionary is a substring of the column Job_Title, fill the column Categories with the value. This is what I tried:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
   if df.loc["Job_Title"].str.contains(cat_type_dic[i]):
      df["Categories"] = df["Categories"].str.replace(cat_type_dic[i], cat_type_dic.get(i))
```

Of course, it's not working. I think I am not accessing correctly to the key and value. Any clue?

This is the message error that I am getting:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 1 for i in range(len(df)):
> ----> 2     if df.iloc["Job_Title"].str.contains(cat_type_dic[i]):
> 3         df["Categories"] = df["Categories"].str.replace(cat_type_dic[i], cat_type_dic.get(i))
>
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in
> **getitem**(self, key)
> 929
> 930             maybe_callable = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
> --> 931             return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
> 932
> 933     def _is_scalar_access(self, key: tuple):
>
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in
> _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)    1561             key = item_from_zerodim(key)    1562             if not is_integer(key):
> -> 1563                 raise TypeError("Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key")    1564     1565             # validate
> the location
>
> TypeError: Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I haven't gone through this in detail, but is there any chance you're just missing an indentation on the if statement? looks like it's on the same level as the for statement

Comment: "if df.loc["Job_Title"].str.contains(cat_type_dic[i]): " I don't think this does what you think it does. .str.contains will return a "Series or Index of boolean values" and python will always evaluate it to True.

Comment: Thanks! I've edited it as I think I pasted the code unproperly. In my code it's correctly indented.

Comment: And i don't understand what you're trying to replace in your categories column as it is not initialized as far as i can tell? And that's probably the source of the error, your trying to access the categories column, but it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: When using `.loc` you need to use either an index value or a series of boolean values (`True` for rows you want to keep and `False` for rows you want to drop). The error is returned because 'Job Title' is not an index value in your dataframe.

Comment: And cat_type_dic[i] and cat_type_dic.get(i) will both return the same value.... why are you replacing a portion of a string by itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following code give you what you need?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Job_Title'] = ['Business Analyst', 'Data Scientist', 'Server Analyst']

cat_type_dic = {'Business': ['CatB1', 'CatB2'], 'Scientist': ['CatS1', 'CatS2', 'CatS3']}

list_keys = list(cat_type_dic.keys())

def label_extracter(x):
    list_matched_keys = list(filter(lambda y: y in x['Job_Title'], list_keys))
    category_label = ' '.join([' '.join(cat_type_dic[key]) for key in list_matched_keys])
    return category_label

df['Categories'] = df.apply(lambda x: label_extracter(x), axis=1)

print(df)

          Job_Title         Categories
0  Business Analyst        CatB1 CatB2
1    Data Scientist  CatS1 CatS2 CatS3
2    Server Analyst
```

###### EDIT: Explaination added. @SofyPond

- `apply` helps when loop necessary.
- I defined a function which checks if `Job_Title` contains a key in the dictionary which is assigned earlier. I preferred convert keys to a list to make checking process easier.
- (list_label renamed to category_label since it is not list anymore) category_label in function `label_extracter` gets values assigned to key in list format. It is converted to str by putting ' ' (white space) between values. In the case, length of list_matched_keys is greater than 0, it will contains list of string which are created by inner `' '.join`. So outer `' '.join` convert it to string format.

Comment: THANKS! It works! I understand that you get the keys from the dictionary and then create another list with the values, right? And then you filter for those rows that in Job Title have that labels, right? I don't get what you do on the list_label part. Could you explain it to me, please? Thanks a lot again!!

Comment: You are right answer is low in terms of explanation. Your comments are correct. But let me edit it and answer your question.

Comment: I edited it. If it is unclear, let me know.

Comment: Thanks!! Makes sense now :)